# How to change calendar view in Input[Month] to Month and Year by default?

Tags: html, angularjs, datepicker, calendar, datetimepicker

I am using AngularJS+Html directive `input`with type [month](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[month]). This allows me to pick month and year only. The code I am using is this:

```html
<input type="month" placeholder="yyyy-MM" required class="form-control" />
```

The calendar view I am getting is this:

[image: Image 1]

Even though date (day) is not selectable, it is little distracting and therefore I want calendar view to be like this by default:

[image: Image 2]

Is this even possible?